# How to categorize a Union Output with CASE?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have done union to combine two select statement (1 gives Entertainer Name & other gives Customer name) output. I want to add a third column to categorize those data into 'customer' and 'entertainer'. How should I do that? I tried using CASE but giving me error.
Below is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CustomerID AS 'ID', CustFirstName AS 'List'
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            CustomerID
        FROM
            musical_preferences
        WHERE
            (SELECT 
                    StyleID
                FROM
                    musical_styles
                WHERE
                    StyleName = 'Contemporary')) 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT
    EntertainerID, EntStageName
FROM
    entertainers
WHERE
    EntertainerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            EntertainerID
        FROM
            entertainer_styles
        WHERE
            (SELECT 
                    StyleID
                FROM
                    musical_styles
                WHERE
                    StyleName = 'Contemporary'));
```

Comment: A UNION (as opposed to a UNION ALL) comes with an implied distinct - if you have an entertainer that happens to have the same id and name as customer id and name then one will be lost - if you add a category column then the intent changes and you may get more rows than your current query https://dbfiddle.uk/-XGP53X_ but a distinct will be implied on each table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (The above query won't run on both...)

Answer (score 1):

you can add as many new columns as you need, the number in both query results must be the same

so add simply text to both

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CustomerID AS 'ID', CustFirstName AS 'List', 'Customer' as tyope
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            CustomerID
        FROM
            musical_preferences
        WHERE
            (SELECT 
                    StyleID
                FROM
                    musical_styles
                WHERE
                    StyleName = 'Contemporary')) 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT
    EntertainerID, EntStageName, 'Entertainber'
FROM
    entertainers
WHERE
    EntertainerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            EntertainerID
        FROM
            entertainer_styles
        WHERE
            (SELECT 
                    StyleID
                FROM
                    musical_styles
                WHERE
                    StyleName = 'Contemporary'));
```

Comment: This works. I would add an alias to the new column in the first query.